# month field not an integer, will not sort properly

Tags: biblatex, biber

With biber 2.6 comes a unnecassary warning:

```
 [15251] Utils.pm:164> WARN - month field 'Apr' in entry 'GSP+08' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.
```

Is the three letter month code no longer supported? the warning clatters the log.

Comment: What happens with lower case 'apr'?

Comment: It's also not recommended to use `year`/`month` fields - the `date` field has many more features and `year`/`month` are considered legacy in `biber` even though they are still supported.

Comment: Case should not matter - can you give a MWE?

Comment: you will find a minimal example together with the bib-file here: http://b-kleine.com/technical/tex_20160918/. Running latexmk on the file and later again biber shows the warning. Regards

Comment: This is only a single bibtex entry. I have however 800+ citations in my document and never before this warning. Therefore I would like to know how to get rid of the warning. It is my understanding that three-letter-code for the month field is still valid. Therefore there should be any warning.

Answer (score 29):

Such month abbreviations are BibTeX macros and if you protect them in braces, they are not parsed as macros but as literal strings. You need, in your example:

```
MONTH = Dec
```

and not

```
MONTH = {Dec}
```

For information, `biber` allows one to turn off such macros with the `--nostdmacros` option.

Answer (score 3):

Month is an integer field, that means January is {1}, February {2} etc.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386058/36296 Without braces the abbreviated month names are ok

Comment: That is true. And one could even give the integer without braces (because BIbTeX allows that). But with most `.bst` files and with `biblatex` it is also valid to use the three-letter abbreviations, but there it is crucial that they are used without braces.

Comment: I should mention though that I believe, correct as this info is, that it does not quite answer the question which specifically asks about whether or not three-letter abbreviations are legal (with or without braces).