# Regex replacement with lowercase monthnames for biblatex/biber to eliminate the warning “month not integer…”

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib, biber, sorting

I had already asked a nearly identical question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438396/regex-replacement-for-biblatex-biber-to-eliminate-the-warning-month-not-integer/438400#438400)

I am using `biblatex` with `biber` from TL2018 for my PhD thesis. Due to various reasons, I am forced to use `Mendeley` for citation managements and cannot switch to another tool now. Mendeley is capable of generating a `bib` file - but it is compatible with **only** the classic `natbib/bibtex` combo (although it correctly escapes special characters).

I understand that with `biblatex/biber` combo, the `month` field is not a string, but rather must be an integer.  So, as expected and discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330179/month-field-not-an-integer-will-not-sort-properly), I get the warning

> WARN - month field 'jan' in entry 'Guo2012' is not an integer - this will probably not sort properly.

(this time for `jan`  wherein unlike my original question, the month does not begin with captial `J`).

For tackling the original question, I used the `regex` given in that question in my preamble (given below)

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Ajan\Z}, replace=1]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Afeb\Z}, replace=2]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Amar\Z}, replace=3]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Aapr\Z}, replace=4]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Amay\Z}, replace=5]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Ajun\Z}, replace=6]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Ajul\Z}, replace=7]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Aaug\Z}, replace=8]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Asep\Z}, replace=9]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Aoct\Z}, replace=10]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Anov\Z}, replace=11]
            \step[fieldsource=month, match=\regexp{\Adec\Z}, replace=12]
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be modified suitably to handle this lowercase situation?

Comment: Can you please provide a *complete* MWE so that we can test our solutions and don't have to make up things that you already have? As I said under the original answer I just tested the code a few minutes ago and it worked for me. I need to see a full MWE and the complete `.blg` file. I don't see how this could be a case issue. The warning message mentions `jan` in lowercase and the code replaces lowercase `jan`.

Comment: Also let me please point out again that even with BibTeX (as backend for `biblatex` or with usual `.bst` files), `month = {jan},` with braces is still unfortunate bordering on completely wrong.

Comment: @moewe It is Mendeley, not me!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean to say with your last comment. Anyway, I have edited my original answer to match both `jan` and `Jan`. I for the life of me can not figure out why the code you posted in this question would not work for the warning you have shown, since everything is lowercase, but since you have not provided a minimal working example, but just code snippets I will not investigate that further until I get to see an MWE.

Comment: In the orginal answer @moewe used `\A(j|J)` in the regex to handle the lower/uppercase. In your snippet above this is missing. Is this intended?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the question to handle upper/lower-case after this question here was asked. I still don't understand how we the code as shown in this question (lowercase `jan`) would not fix the warning with a lowercase `jan`. But there is no full code example, so I don't know what might be going on. Sorry for the confusion.